# How to plot multiple, separate graphs in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of over 300K rows and over 20 years. I'm trying to create a Load Duration Curve for every year for XX years (so # of MW used every hour of the year (8760 hours for every year or 8784 for leap year). Currently I make a new dataframe by filtering by year and then reordering by descending order of MW used (descending order for the curve) and then create another column to match the row order so that I can use that column as a placeholder for the x-axis. Seems pretty inefficient and could be difficult to update if needed (see playground for what I've been doing). I also don't want to use facet_wrap() because the graphs are too small for what is needed.

Dummy_file:
Where hrxhr is the running total of hours in a given year.

| YEAR | MONTH | DAY | HOUR OF DAY | MW | Month_num | Date | Date1 | hrxhr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | Dec | 31 | 22 | 2416 | 12 | 2023-12-31 | 365 | 8758 |
| 2023 | Dec | 31 | 23 | 2412 | 12 | 2023-12-31 | 365 | 8759 |
| 2023 | Dec | 31 | 24 | 2400 | 12 | 2023-12-31 | 365 | 8760 |
| 2024 | Jan | 01 | 1 | 2271 | 12 | 2024-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023 | Jan | 01 | 2 | 2264 | 12 | 2024-01-01 | 1 | 2 |

```
### ------------ Load in source ------------ ###
dummy_file <- 'Dummydata.csv'
forecast_df <- read_csv(dummy_file)

### ---- Order df by MW (load) and YEAR ---- ###
ordered_df <- forecast_df[order(forecast_df$MW, decreasing = TRUE), ]
ordered_df <- ordered_df[order(ordered_df$YEAR, decreasing = FALSE), ]

### -------------- Playground -------------- ###
## Create a dataframe for the forecast for calendar year 2023
cy23_df <- ordered_df[ordered_df$YEAR == 2023,]

## Add placeholder column for graphing purposes (add order number)
cy23_df$placeholder <- row.names(cy23_df)
## Check df structure and change columns as needed
str(cy23_df)
# Change placeholder column from character to numeric for graphing purposes
cy23_df$placeholder <- as.numeric(cy23_df$placeholder)
# Check if changed correctly
class(cy23_df$placeholder) #YES

## Load duration curve - Interactive
LF_cy23_LDC <- plot_ly(cy23_df, 
                       x= ~placeholder, 
                       y= ~MW, 
                       type= 'scatter', 
                       mode = 'lines',
                       hoverinfo = 'text',
                       text = paste("Megawatts: ", cy23_df$MW,
                                    "Date: ", cy23_df$MONTH, cy23_df$DAY,
                                    "Hour: ", cy23_df$hrxhr)) %>% 
  layout(title = 'CY2023 Load Forecast - LDC')
# "Hour: ", orderby_MW$yrhour)) 

saveWidget(LF_cy23_LDC, "cy23_LDC.html")
```

Current Output for CY2023:
[Yaxis Megawatts used (MW) and Xaxis is a placeholder (placeholder)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya6S4.png) and then I just repeat the playground code for the rest of the years, but change 2023 to 2024, then 2025, etc.

Sorry if this is a long post, tmi, or not enough information. I'm fairly new to R and this community. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you make the year to color of the line? Or do you want each plot to be separately generated?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to have the years as separate graphs/separate pngs or html files. The placeholder variable I created makes it a little weird too (I need to plot the amount of MW used every hour (in a given year) (aka HOUR OF DAY) in descending order.) (I don't have the placeholder variable here, but basically creates a new column and numbers based on the MW in descending order so I can plot...so the x axis/placeholder is just a filler.)

Comment: You MAY try using `purrr::walk` or some variant thereof. I'm curious as to why you are using an interactive plotter instead of something static like ggplot - do you need to maintain the interactivity?

Comment: The interactive tool tips help display the date of the most (to the least) forecasted MW used in a given year. The order isn't forecasted the same each year. (Other program was used for forecasting data.) It isn't absolutely necessary, but would be helpful/a plus to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply generalize your *playground* process in a user-defined method, then iterate through years with `lapply`.

```r
# USER DEFINED METHOD TO RUN A SINGLE YEAR
build_year_plot <- function(year) {
    ### -------------- Playground -------------- ### 
    ## Create a dataframe for the forecast for calendar year
    cy_df <- ordered_df[ordered_df$YEAR == year,] 

    ## Add placeholder column for graphing purposes (add order number) 
    cy_df$placeholder <- row.names(cy_df) 

    ## Check df structure and change columns as needed 
    str(cy_df)

    # Change placeholder column from character to numeric for graphing purposes 
    cy_df$placeholder <- as.numeric(cy_df$placeholder) 

    # Check if changed correctly 
    class(cy_df$placeholder) #YES 

    ## Load duration curve - Interactive 
    LF_cy_LDC <- plot_ly(
        cy_df, x = ~placeholder, y = ~MW, type= 'scatter', 
        mode = 'lines', hoverinfo = 'text', 
        text = paste(
            "Megawatts: ", cy_df$MW, 
            "Date: ", cy_df$MONTH, cy_df$DAY, 
            "Hour: ", cy_df$hrxhr
        )
    ) %>% layout( # USING BASE R 4.1.0+ PIPE
        title = paste0('CY', year, ' Load Forecast - LDC')
    )

    saveWidget(LF_cy_LDC, paste0("cy", year-2000, "_LDC.html"))

    return(LF_cy_LDC)
}

# CALLER TO RUN THROUGH SEVERAL YEARS
LF_cy_plots <- lapply(2023:2025, build_year_plot)
```

Consider even `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply` and roughly equivalent to `split` + `lapply`) and avoid the year indexing. Notice input parameter changes below and variables used in title and filename:

```r
# USER DEFINED METHOD TO RUN A SINGLE DATA FRAME
build_year_plot <- function(cy_df) {
    ### -------------- Playground -------------- ### 
    ## Add placeholder column for graphing purposes (add order number) 
    cy_df$placeholder <- row.names(cy_df) 

    ...SAME AS ABOVE...

    ) %>% layout(
        title = paste0('CY', cy_df$YEAR[1], ' Load Forecast - LDC')
    )

    saveWidget(LF_cy_LDC, paste0("cy", cy_df$YEAR[1]-2000, "_LDC.html"))

    return(LF_cy_LDC)
}

# CALLER TO RUN THROUGH SEVERAL YEARS
LF_cy_plots <- by(ordered_df, ordered_df$YEAR, build_year_plot)
```

Counterparts in tidyverse would be [**`purrr.map`**](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html):

```r
# METHOD RECEIVES YEAR (lapply counterpart)
LF_cy_plots <- purrr::map(2023:2025, build_year_plot)

# METHOD RECEIVES DATA FRAME (by counterpart)
LF_cy_plots <- ordered_year %>%
    split(.$YEAR) %>%
    purrr::map(build_year_plot)
```